# Compass vendor prefixes does not include Opera prefix

Tags: sass, compass, vendor-prefix

I've installed compass recently to get benefit from its features, especially the vendor prefixes.

When I do something like this :

```
@include box-sizing(border-box);
```

I get :

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

But what about other prefixes like Opera prefix `-o-box-sizing` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compass does not blindly add vendor prefixes to every property, it only adds the ones that browsers actually use by checking with [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/).  Opera has never required prefixes for the box-sizing property, so Compass does not add it.